# Печать jpg файла в С#

Tags: c#

Как из программы написанной на С# напечатать файл с расширением .jpg ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750659/print-images-c-net

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
// Путь к изображению.
string file = @"C:\1.png";

using(var pd = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument())
{
    pd.PrintPage += (o,e) =>
    {
        var img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(file);

        e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, new Point(50, 50));     
    };
    pd.Print();      
}
```

Comment: а если надо на предварительный просмотр, то как быть?

Comment: @VladimirTsybin: То выведите отдельное окно обычным образом.

Comment: @VladD: как раз и нужен код который откроет файл jpg из программы (С#)

Comment: @VladimirTsybin: Давайте-ка выясним, что вам на самом деле надо. Вы умеете создать пустое окно?

Comment: надо распечатать файл jpg c предварительным просмотром, но открыть файл нужно из программы С#

Comment: @VladimirTsybin: Вы не ответили на вопрос. Если вы умеете писать оконные приложения, то непонятно, почему предварительный просмотр вызывает у вас проблемы. Если вы не умеете писать оконные приложения, то вам нужно найти книгу и научиться.

Comment: @VladD: Вы прочитали что я писал до этого, повторюсь: надо распечатать файл jpg c предварительным просмотром, но открыть файл нужно из программы С#

Comment: C оконными приложениями проблем нет!!!

Comment: в гугле есть все http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/Thread/120970/printpreview-picturebox-image.aspx там даже пример есть приложения

Comment: @VlaD, он, вероятно, стандартный диалог с настройками принтера хочет и предпросмотр в нём же. Если ничего не путаю, в VB6 что-то такое было...